# How to fix end-of-input with two Boolean statements

Tags: ruby, integer

I'm filtering some Array elements in Ruby and want to filter the positive ones, only if they're all Integers.

```
l = [1,2,'a','b']

l.select do |number|
  new_array = [] 
  new_array.push(number) if number.positive? && number.kind_of? Integer
end
```

but I got a `Syntax error` asking for `expecting end-of-input`.

Why doesn't `number.positive? && number.kind_of? Integer` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround it in parentheses:

```
new_array.push(number) if number.positive? && (number.kind_of? Integer)
```

Which results in `` undefined method `positive?' for "a":String `` because `positive?` isn't defined for the strings `'a'` and `'b'`.

Checking the type first works:

```
new_array.push(number) if (number.kind_of? Integer) && number.positive?
```

Comment: add the parens to the method call?

`number.kind_of?(Integer)`

Answer (score 2):

The `select` method is a filtering method and it needs a boolean value that describes if the element should or shouldn't be in the resulting output. In that block you should focus on one thing and one thing only: *Describing in minimal terms the acceptance criteria for the filter*.

What you're doing here is declaring a local variable, conditionally populating it, then throwing it away, and also discarding the resulting output.

What you really want is to strip this down to the basics:

```
l = [1,2,'a','b']

filtered = l.select do |number|
  number.positive? && number.kind_of? Integer
end
```

Don't forget to capture the result of this operation or it goes straight in the trash.

There's still a bug here because strings don't have a `positive?` method, so just reverse the order:

```
filtered = l.select do |number|
  number.kind_of?(Integer) && number.positive?
end
```

That requires adding brackets to the `kind_of?` call to avoid ambiguity. `&&` is a very aggressive operator and will interpret the call as this if not properly contained:

```
number.kind_of?(Integer && number.positive?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, Monkey patching `Object` class:

```
module MyPatches
  def integer_and_positive?
    kind_of?(Integer) && self > 0
  end
end

Object.include MyPatches
```

For using this way, with [Array#keep_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-keep_if):

```
l.keep_if(&:integer_and_positive?)
#=> [1, 2]
```

Note: it alters the original array, for avoiding it use [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-select).